# How to read xml file using python?

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I I have a xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Automation_Config>
    <Path>
        <Log>.\SERVER.log</Log>
        <Flag_Path>.\Flag</Flag_Path>
        <files>.\PO</files>
    </Path>

</Automation_Config>
```

I want to read the xml file and get the element of those, and assign to variable.

I tried this, but I can not get the element of Log.

```
import xml.dom.minidom
def main ():
    Load_XML = xml.dom.minidom.parse('D:/Config.xml')
    print (Load_XML.nodeName)
    print (Load_XML.firstChild.tagName)

    Log = Load_XML.getElementsByTagName ("Log")
    print (Log)

main()
```

Comment: try with https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-xml-files-in-python/

Comment: I strongly advice *against* using `xml.dom.minidom`. Unless you have a very specific need to work with the *very minimal and basic* W3C DOM API, you want to be using the [`xml.etree.ElementTree` API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) instead. The DOM API is aimed as a minimal common ground between lots of programming languages, many not nearly as expressive as Python. As a consequence, it is very, very, *very* tedious to have to work with.

Comment: With the `ElementTree` API, getting the string contents of the first `Log` element is as trivial as `tree = ET.parse(filename)` then `value = tree.find(".//Log").text`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ElementTree`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('Config.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.findall('.//Log'))
```

Output:

```
pawel@pawel-XPS-15-9570:~/test$ python parse_xml.py 
[<Element 'Log' at 0x7fb3f2eee9f
```

Answer (score 0):

Below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Automation_Config>
    <Path>
        <Log>.\SERVER.log</Log>
        <Flag_Path>.\Flag</Flag_Path>
        <files>.\PO</files>
    </Path>

</Automation_Config>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for idx,log_element in enumerate(root.findall('.//Log')):
  print('{}) Log value: {}'.format(idx,log_element.text))
```

output

```
0) Log value: .\SERVER.log
```